# Why does writeBytes discard each character's high eight bits?

Tags: java

I wanted to use [DataOutputStream#writeBytes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeBytes%28java.lang.String%29), but was running into errors. Description of `writeBytes(String)` from the Java Documentation:

> Writes out the string to the underlying output stream as a sequence of bytes. Each character in the string is written out, in sequence, by discarding its high eight bits.

I think the problem I'm running into is due to the part about "discarding its high eight bits". What does that mean, and why does it work that way?

Comment: Is your code supposed to be handling unicode?  Specifically, non-English characters?

Comment: No (to comment I need to add this part so there are enough characters)

Comment: Based on the other answers, I'd suggest appending a 0 byte to the start/end (depending on the Endian-style) of each byte to reconstitute the original representation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most Western programmers tend to think in terms of ASCII, where one character equals one byte, but Java `String`s are 16-bit Unicode. `writeBytes` just writes out the lower byte, which for ASCII/ISO-8859-1 is the "character" in the C sense.

Answer (score 5):

The `char` data type is a single **`16-bit`** Unicode character. It has a minimum value of `'\u0000'` (or 0) and a maximum value of `'\uffff'` (or `65,535` inclusive). But The `byte` data type is an **`8-bit`** signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of `-128` and a maximum value of `127` (inclusive). That is why this function is writing the low-order byte of each char in the string from first to last. Any information in the high-order byte is lost. In other words, it assumes the string contains only characters whose value is between `0`and `255`.

You may look into the [`writeUTF(String s)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF%28java.lang.String%29) method, which, retains the information in the high-order byte as well as the length of the string. First it writes the number of characters in the string onto the underlying output stream as a 2-byte unsigned int between `0` and `65,535`. Next it encodes the string in `UTF-8` and writes the bytes of the encoded string to the underlying output stream. This allows a data input stream reading those bytes to completely reconstruct the string.